# sigploit in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I was curious to know if there was any way to use sigploit in MacBook terminal ,a descriptive answer would be appreciated s

in my case im unable to successfully install requirements.txt and the python too sucks ,I've tried installing and reinstalling python multiple times but still im unable to use python command

Answer (score 0):

SigPloit is primarily designed to run on Linux systems and is not officially supported on macOS.
One of the ways around this is to use Docker or VM.

In addition, you can try the following:-

1. Use pip to install the requirements one by one, instead of trying to install them all at once using the requirements.txt file.
2. Try to use the python3 command instead of python to run your script and check if it works.